# Extracting contours as shapefile from DTM (tif) in QGIS?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, qgis-2, lidar, gdal-contour, civil3d

I am looking to convert a tif. file from the Scottish Remote Sensing Portal (Scottish LiDAR) into contours which can be used for a surface in civils 3D.

I have tried this myself with a full DTM and a clipped DTM and when I try to extract contours to a shapefile (.SHP), I get the message:

```
ERROR 6: GDALDriver::Create() ... no create method implemented for this format.
```

I have very little experience with QGIS but I know that this can be achieved in ArcGIS.

I am still running version 2.18.27 as well but will gladly upgrade if necessary.

Comment: did you put .shp on the end of the file you specified for the output?

Comment: Ian, I have not been doing this but it does not appear to be the issue. I have now changed the output file name to contours.shp and saved it as an ESRI shapefile with the encoding set to system and still I get the same response.

Comment: does qgis2 show you the gdal command? if so can you add it to the question

Comment: Sorry Ian, is this the GDAL command? gdal_contour -i 10.0 -f ESRIJSON "C:/Users/Workstation 012/Desktop/DTM_NS31 clipped.tif" "C:/Users/Workstation 012/Desktop/contour.shp"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that QGis is trying to create an [ESRIJSON output file](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/esrijson.html) (possibly because you asked for that, or more likely it's confused) but that is a read only format. So if you change the output format to shapefile (the command should change to `gdal_contour -i 10.0 -f "ESRI Shapefile" "C:/Users/Workstation 012/Desktop/DTM_NS31 clipped.tif" "C:/Users/Workstation 012/Desktop/contour.shp"` or you can just run the command in the OSGeo4W shell:

```
gdal_contour -i 10.0 -a ELEV "C:/Users/Workstation 012/Desktop/DTM_NS31 clipped.tif" "C:/Users/Workstation 012/Desktop/contour.shp"
```

Comment: This appears to be the problem and with your command I have managed to produce contours for Civils 3D. However, I still can't seem to get QGIS to automatically change the output file to "ESRI Shapefile". Should I upgrade my QGIS or is this something which I am doing.

Comment: I would upgrade - definitly works fine in 3.10